# ImageView width incorrectly scaled on Nexus 4?

Tags: android, imageview, horizontalscrollview, nexus-4

I'm using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635903/get-maximum-horizontalscrollview-scroll-amount). The following line works on *all* my devices, except my `Nexus 4`:

```
int imageWidth = horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredWidth();
```

The layout is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_scroller"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Into this `HorizontalScrollView` I programmatically create a bitmap that is around 500x1000 pixels. Hence, the image will be stretched to fill *roughly* 1200x2400 (see [centerCrop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)). **Thus, the width of the `ImageView` should be 2400.** And it is! On my Nexus 7, Samsung S3 Mini and some other low-density devices. But not on my Nexus 4! On Nexus 4, it does indeed have its height stretched but not the width (yeah, unbelievable): 1000x1000 pixels. I've tried both `getWidth()` and `getMeasuredWidth()`. And when I try to scroll it, I can see only 50% of the image horizontally (but 100% vertically).

### UPDATE 1:

Looking at `mDrawMatrix` of my `ImageView`, I can see that it differs:

Nexus 7:
Matrix{[2.2979167, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 2.2979167, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

Nexus 4:
Matrix{[2.1458333, 0.0, **-623.0**][0.0, 2.1458333, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

### UPDATE 2:

This is a bug in `ImageView.onMeasure()` in Android 4.2.2, fixed in 4.3. **The question now is, how do I add this fix in 4.2.2?** Overriding `onMeasure()` is not 100% trivial since a lot of private functions are being called.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Do you have a link for the bug report?

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue on Samsung Galaxy S4 4.2.2 and S3 4.1.1, whatever I did, a programmatically-set Bitmap would not scale to fill the width of it's parent ViewGroup. I tried all combinations of scaleType to no avail.

For me the solution was to set set the density on the bitmap to a specific value before displaying it.

```
        Bitmap myBitmap = ... 

        // S3 and S4 get confused about displaying bitmaps without a specific density,
        // and fail to scale them properly. Setting the density to this value helps (is possible ANY density helps, but haven't tested this)
        myBitmap.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH);

        myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```