# Scroll ScrollView to middle

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm trying to scroll in Android a HorizontalScrollView programmatically.

However I just found this method:

`scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)`

And I'm looking forward to scroll the view to exactly the middle.

Any tip?

I know that there's a method to scroll to an exact position:
`setScrollX` but the parameter should be calculated somehow I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = scroll.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
         scroll.scrollTo(scroll.getChildAt(0).getWidth()/2, 0);
    }
});
```

This is working!

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`scrollTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) and scroll it by getting the y bottom coordinate divided by 2.

```
myScrollView.scrollTo(0, myScrollView.getBottom()/2);
```

For an horizontal scroll view :

```
myScrollView.scrollTo(widthOfScrollView/2, 0);
```

Comment: I'm looking for HorizontalScrollView. This is for a vertical.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán You can also use scrollTo but with `getRight()` on the x coordinate. Does it works ?

Comment: No. This is my code `HorizontalScrollView scrollViewSplash = (HorizontalScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewSplash);
   scrollViewSplash.scrollTo(scrollViewSplash.getRight()/2, 0);`

Comment: May look a this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635903/get-maximum-horizontalscrollview-scroll-amount and try to get the width of the scroll view.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I found the other answers didn't work for me. The following worked well.

```
val vto = viewTreeObserver
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        val maxScroll = scrollView.getChildAt(0).width - scrollView.width
        scrollView.scrollTo(maxScroll / 2, 0)

        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to do it in Kotlin without using a OnGlobalLayoutListener, where wideView is the view within the ScrollView.

wideView.apply {
post { scrollView.scrollTo((left + right - scrollView.width) / 2, 0) }
}